# Empty HTTP response headers and body

Tags: http, httpresponse

I am able to consistently reproduce this problem where I request a URL from my server and I get back a 200 code but the response headers and response body are empty.  If I monitor incoming traffic on my web server I never see the request come in.  My web server sits behind a proxy server, if I monitor traffic there, I also do not see the request come in.

Any ideas as to where this empty response might be coming from, or tips as to what situations can result in an empty response like this?

Comment: run tcpdump or windump on the computer you're testing from: make the invisible visible.

Comment: So you make a request to a server, but the server doesn't see it? Maybe you are connecting to *another* server.

Comment: It's definitely the right server, there could be some sort of caching going on, preventing the server from actually receiving any request.  Looking into *dump to see what it can tell me...

Comment: The request is a GET request.  The issue only occurs when accessing the URL using the internet address and not when using our internal network address.  I am investigating that the issue could potentially be within our firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a GET request size limit on our internal firewall proxy server.  We were able to reduce the size at which we switch from a GET to a POST request in our code to avoid the limit.